# to much rerendering in react after using socket io

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

am doing something similar to omegle, this is some of my code, look at the useEffect functions.

```
const Messanger =(props)=>{
let socket = props.socket;
let intro;
const myId = socket.id;
const [readOnly,setReadOnly] = useState(true);
const [messages,setMessages]=useState([]);
const [stranger_name,setStranger_name] = useState(null);
const [disconnected,setDisconnected] = useState(false);
const [room,setRoom] = useState(null);
let messageRef = React.createRef();
let messagesEnd =React.createRef();
```

when the server find a match bettwen two users, it connects them together in one room and then , it sends to both of them a joinRoom socket request to inform the front that they are connected

```
useEffect(()=>{

  socket.once("joinRoom",(data)=>{
    setDisconnected(false);

  setMessages([]);
  setStranger_name(data.name);
  setRoom(data.room);
   setReadOnly(false);
  console.log("JOING ROOM")
});


},[stranger_name])
```

when user receiver a message, this script will be triggerd

```
useEffect(()=>{
  socket.once('messageToClient',(data)=>{
    setMessages([...messages,{message:data.message,id:data.id}])         
    });
    scrollToBottom();
},[messages])
```

and here before rendering i console log some text to see how many times i render

```
console.log('render')

return (DOM)
```

the main issue is that each time i disconnect with user that am chating with, and start again, the DOM re-render to many times , for example the console.log code get triggerd 4 times when message received , and when i start to chat with another user, the console.log('render') function gets triggert 8 times and so on

Comment: Sounds like it's time to sit down and put some time into forming a true [mcve]. Not so much for us, but for _you_ to gain insight into what your code is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are essentially creating an infinite loop by resubscribing to the socket event when the `messages` changes, causing `setMessages` to be triggered multiple times, which causes your hook to resubscribe etc.etc.

the following is a temp. fix but not the complete answer as you should handle socket messeges outside of your component, store them in redux and then consume them.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  socket.once('messageToClient',(data)=>{
    setMessages((prevMessages)=>[...prevMessages,{message:data.message,id:data.id}])         
    });
    scrollToBottom();
},[])
```

Comment: thank you alot. 
actually first time i removed the (messages) from the array to avoid that loop you was are talkig about, but after that , the setMessage func didn't work correctly , it was setting the messages to only one message, the prevMessages was always null

but now i change the setMessages the same way you did and it works,
can you tell me the different bettwen 
    setMessages((prevMessages)=>[...prevMessages,{message:data.message,id:data.id}])         
and this
   setMessages([...prevMessages,{message:data.message,id:data.id}])          
?

Comment: and also , is that normal that my DOM re-renders on each setState?
for example , i have this function witch contain 4 setStates
```
const heDisconnecting = ()=>{
  setDisconnected(true);
  setInchat(!inchat);
  setRoom(null);
  setReadOnly(true);
}
```
why the dom re-render on each of these setStates function? and is that normal? 
why it don't re-render once after the parent function finish?

Comment: @MohamadAlasly glad I could help!
1. question; the difference is that you get the previousState state while updating it so it is not needed to pass it in - If you do and have it outside as a dependency in your useEffect, it retriggers your callback (since the dependency changes) which can cause many rerendering
2. question; yes, that is normal and how hooks/setState work. If you update multiple things at the same time, you could also just use one `useState({inChat:...,messeges:..., disconnected:...})` which would only cause one render